# Why was this Seven Samurais question migrated?

Tags: discussion

I noticed earlier today that this question [Seven Samurai Crests](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72491/seven-samurai-crests) on Movies had been migrated from History.  This question has issues and really shouldn't have been migrated.

When migrating to other sites, please keep the points in this post in mind:  [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/161679)